# How do I create a circular progress bar in Unity3D 5?

Tags: unity, graphic-effects, loading

I am new to programming and Unity3D. I want to show a circular progress bar starting invisible and growing in 3 seconds to a circular line when reloading is done. How can I do that?

Comment: create an animation and then set the progress of the animation to loading to the progress of loading.

Answer (score 2):

1. GameObject->UI->Image
2. Put your unfilled circle outline sprite in image.
3. Change the Image type to Filled. Then you can play with Fill amount property and also control in through code.

Some credit goes to Shubham who I copied from instructions on a slightly different subject.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was after, if I understand you correctly this would create a circle that slowly expands. I believe the OP was after just the outline of a circle (i.e. non-filled). Also, this lacks an explanation of how to link the animation to the loading progress.

Comment: This can be easily done using a unfilled circle.... OP mentioned nothing about animation.

Comment: Sorry if I was wrong, but I assumed setting the sprite to '_fill_' would result in a solid circle (rather than an outline). And by animation I was simply referring to "_starting invisible and growing in 3 seconds_" in the question.

Comment: Try it one day, us programmers use it as an easy way to stay away from animation ;) Can be used for most things of this type. "Fill" is just the setting in Unity (There is also a fill center option for sliced sprites but that's seperate).

Comment: All I could find on the '_fill_' setting was [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html), though I'm not sure if that's what the OP wanted - which I took to be a circle that gradually expands in size.  I can't see how to do that with the 'fill' property. I'm not familiar with Unity, so if you could explain how it's done (and update your answer) that would be great.

Comment: This is a video example of the type of results you can get: https://youtu.be/CWweOvS4uiE It's late is this what OP is looking for?

Comment: Maybe you should mention that it's the RADIAL fill method which does the trick :)